# what's the correct way to lay out three child divs with one on left, one in middle and one on right of parent?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out an elegant way to have my divs display as follows, in CSS

```
---------------------------------------------------------
|                                                       | 
| child div 1           child div 2          child div 3|
|                                                       |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

the idea being that the box is a parent div and it can be of any width and these three children would always line up with 1 on left, 2 in middle and 3 on right.

For bonus points, if they can be aligned vertically centered in the parent div that would be fantastic, but I can get by without that.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to set the width of either the parent div and use percentages to set the child divs widths, or you need to give the child divs fixed widths and allow the parent div to expand around them. Here is some code that you can start with:

HTML:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="sidebar">

    </div><div class="main">

    </div><div class="sidebar">

    </div>
</div>
```

*Notice how the closing `</div>` and the succeeding `<div>` are touching. For inline and inline-block elements to touch, there cannot be space between them in the markup.*

CSS:

```
.block { 
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block; }
.block .sidebar {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
.block .main {
    background: blue;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
.block div { margin: 0; }
.block p { margin: 0; }
```

If you decide to make `.block` a fixed width, remove `display: inline-block`.

*The following only applies when `.block` does not have a fixed width:*

If you need to horizontally center `.block`, you `margin: 0 auto` will not work because `.block` is an inline element, which is needed to make it wrap around the fixed-width elements. You need to add `text-align: center` to its parent element (which might be your `body` element if `.block` is your outermost element), and then add `text-align: left` to `.block`.

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/jfQqF/

Comment: Also, if you're looking to have equal height backgrounds, I highly recommend you check out [this article on A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).

Answer (score 1):

**Table-row**

```
 list-display: table-row;
```

on the parent div and list-display: table-cell; on the children.
Then text-align right on child div 3. Advantages are that you don't need to specify a width.

**Floating**

```
float: left;
```

Set a width on all three children divs and use: float: left; You may beed a fourth div in the parent with clear: both; to clear those floats properly.

Comment: I don't understand the floating option... why would setting float:left; get the second div to sit in the middle and the third on the right?

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/FR9wm/, see also how if you add a fourth div in the parent you'll get the parent to get the height of it's children: http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/agf73/